# Nested Loops in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, django-templates

I have in my models Projects and Tasks. I'd like to display on the template:

Project 1

- Task 1:1
- Task 1:2
- Task 1:n

Project 2

- Task 2:1
- Task 2:n

Project n

Here's the model

```
class Projects(models.Model):
    slug_project = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    project_due_date = models.DateTimeField()
    project_lead_time = models.IntegerField()
    project_assignee = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    project_status = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_name


class Tasks(models.Model):
    slug_task = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    task_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    task_desc = models.TextField(null=True)
    task_channel = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    task_id = models.ForeignKey(Projects, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    task_due_date = models.DateTimeField('Due Date')
    task_lead_time = models.IntegerField()
    task_assignee = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.task_name
```

I'm not sure how to construct the view properly but here's my code:

```
class somePage(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'dashboard/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'project_object'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return the last five published Coupons."""
        return Projects.objects.order_by('project_name')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(somePage, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # context['tasks'] = Tasks.objects.order_by('task_name') #this would display ALL tasks
        context.update({
            'all_project': Projects.objects.all(),
            'all_tasks': Tasks.objects.filter(task__id=self.object),
        })
        return context
```

And I'm also not confident how construct the template:

```
{% if project_object %}
{% for project_name in project_object %}
<div class="card_row_h1">
<a href="{% url 'dashboard:task_list' project_name.id %}">
{{ project_name }}
</a> 
</div>

{% if all_tasks %} 
{% for task_name in tasks %}
<div class="card_row_h2" style="width: 100%; padding-left: 30px;">
<small>{{ task_name }}</small>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
<div class="card_row_h2" style="width: 100%;">
No Tasks for This Project
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The result is that the Projects display correctly, but under each project I get nothing for 'all_tasks' and it displays 'No tasks for this project' or if I use 'tasks' (see commented line in view), it displays all tasks for all the projects over and over.

So there are two questions here:

1. how do I construct the view, and
2. how do I construct the template?

I'm a newbie but I've been stuck on this for over a day. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `task_id = models.ForeignKey(Projects` horrible choice for an attr name. It's `project`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with the conventions. Can you please explain further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good start! I think you can simplify this a little. You can get the set of tasks for a project using the reverse look up for foreign keys. Without setting the `related_name` argument in the task models ForeignKey, you can access the tasks associated to a project using `some_project.task_set.all()`. You can even do this in the template so you dont need to worry about overriding the context data for the view:

views.py

```
class MainPage(ListView):
    template_name = 'dashboard/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'projects'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Projects.objects.order_by('project_name')
```

index.html

```
{% for project in projects %}
    <div class="card_row_h1">
        <a href="{% url 'dashboard:task_list' project.id %}">
            {{ project.project_name }}
        </a>
    </div>
    {% if project.task_set.all %}
         {% for task in project.task_set.all %}
             <div class="card_row_h2" style="width: 100%; padding-left: 30px;">
             <small>{{ task.task_name }}</small>
         {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <div class="card_row_h2" style="width: 100%;">
            No Tasks for This Project
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you wanted, in your Tasks model, you could change
`task_id = models.ForeignKey(Projects, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

to `project = models.ForeignKey(Projects, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="tasks"`

This would make the field name a little more intuitive, and also let you access the Tasks for a project just by doing:
`my_project_instance.tasks.all()`

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful and clear. Is there a place where I can see some sample code for things like this? Its surprising that despite all my searching, it was very difficult to find answers.

Comment: Glad it helped! Is there anything in particular part you're looking for docs/examples of? For using class based views, the django docs are quite useful: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/ also as a reference, ccbv is really useful https://ccbv.co.uk/ (especially when things get a little more complicated)